# Python is showing empty list when using os.listdir()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

This is the line of code:

```
names = os.listdir(SAVE_PATH + "/temp")
```

I tried to debug it and the `names` are an empty list `[]`.

SAVE_PATH is imported from a different file and it is working properly

```
SAVE_PATH = r"C:\Users\rohit\Downloads\YouTube"
```

[Files in that folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tnrm.png)

Edit:
This worked:

```
print(os.listdir(r"C:\Users\rohit\Downloads\YouTube\temp"))
```

[code link](https://github.com/fjueic/YouTube-MP3-Downloader/tree/master)
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be appending `\temp` ? It might be easier to use `pathlib`, which can easily mix Windows-style and Unix-style pathing.

Comment: You used a slash instead of a backslash.

Comment: i downloaded those files using same file.

Comment: there should not be any problem. I will check pathlib

Comment: @BernieD using slash didn't work.

Comment: @sj95126 using back slash `\`didn't work.

Comment: @sj95126 same goes with path lib

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Have you tried `names = os.listdir(os.path.join(SAVE_PATH, "temp"))` ?

Comment: @abokey here i just uploaded files to github. Code have no Comments but it should be ok cause problem is at specific line. [link](https://github.com/fjueic/YouTube-MP3-Downloader/tree/master)

Comment: backslash didn't work because it needs to be escaped or you need to use a raw string: `names = os.listdir(SAVE_PATH + r"\temp")`. I'd use pathlib though.

Answer (score 0):

In between all those uncommented code I accidentally changed `SAVE_PATH` which caused this error.

I'm sorry for wasting your time guys.